# ¿Para qué sirve "return" en una funcion void?

Tags: java

Ejemplo:

```
public void transferir(int cantidad) {
   if (cantidad<100) {return;}
   cantidad-=10;
}
```

¿Para qué sirve ese return? Si se cumple la condición se sigue el flujo de ejecución y si no no se termina de ejecutar el método?

Comment: Se utiliza para salir de la función, ya que no retornas nada.

Comment: La lógica en esa función indica que si `cantidad` es menor que 100, entonces no se siga ejecutando código de dicha función (se sale de la función). Para salir de una función se usa la sentencia `return`. Si `cantidad` es mayor o igual a 100 se ejecuta la linea que está después de la condición `if`. Y aunque no se usa `return` al final, al ser una función que devuelve `void`, no es necesaria la misma.

Comment: Se siente raro decir esto pero: Esos comentarios son respuestas y van abajo, en las respuestas! :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Te lo explicaré con un diagrama de flujo:

[image: diagrama de flujo]

Este tipo de diagrama lo generé a partir del código mediante la herramienta [code2flow](https://app.code2flow.com/)

Como verás tras el condicional se decide si proceder o no.

En tu caso muy particular nada de tu código tiene sentido semántico, pues
la variable cantidad nuna se usa fuera de tu función, ni se realiza nada con ella.

Pero suponiendo que no fuera un primitivo, podrías usar ese método para aplicar un descuento si se cumple cierta condición.

Adicionalmente te comento... que desafortunadamente se considera una mala práctica el modificar los valores de tus parámetros, ya que esto a veces puede llevrte a errores sutiles.

A esta forma de poner código en la que al entrar a tu método y regresar si no cumple co cierta condición se le conoce en la literatura como *early return*.

Sin retorno prematuro

```
public void unaFuncion(boolean variableaprobar)
{
    if (variableaprobar)
    {
        // haz algo
    }
}
```

Con retorno prematuro:

```
public void unaFuncion(boolean someCondition)
{
    if (!variableaprobar)
        return;

    // haz algo
}
```

Si bien hay opiniones muy diversas sobre cual es mejor, me enfocaré en lo importante y es que son dos formas de expresar exactamente lo mismo.

En la primera la forma de pensar es imperativa, le estamos diciendo paso por paso que hacxer como si fuera una receta.

En la forma segunda (retorno prematuro) demostramos una mentalidad matemática, es la forma en que se escriben los teoremas.

Nuestra condición en el retorno prematuro hace las veces de corolario. Si nos acostumbramos a esta forma, programar recursivamente nos será más natural, pues la primera parte será nuestro paso base (o como lo define la literatura [condición de parada](https://issuu.com/universidaddavinci/docs/unidad_6._an__lisis_de_algoritmos_r)) y lo demás será nuestro paso recursivo, sin preocuparnos por una explosión recursiva infinita ya que en el paso base establecimos primero las condiciones para terminar nuestra función recursiva.

Modificando un poco tu ejemplo verás como se puede hacer esto:

```
public void imprimenumero(final int cantidad) { // final nos asegura que nunca se modifique su valor por accidente
  
   // paso 1
   if (cantidad<1){
      return;
   }
   System.out.println(cantidad);
   imprimenumero(cantidad);
}
```

Comment: Muy bien, excelente respuesta, +1.